# Generic Builder in Java

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

I created a builder for a lookup table and using it as shown below.

```
public class RaceCodeDataBuilder {

    private RaceCode raceCode;  

    public RaceCodeDataBuilder() {
        raceCode = new RaceCode();
    }

    public RaceCodeDataBuilder code(String code) {
        raceCode.setCode(code);     
        return this;
    }

    public RaceCodeDataBuilder displayName(String displayName) {
        raceCode.setDisplayName(displayName);
        return this;
    }

    public RaceCode build() {
        return raceCode;
    }

}
```

**Using this builder in a test:**

```
   RaceCode mockRaceCode = new RaceCodeDataBuilder()
                         .code("2054-5")
                         .displayName("Black or African American")
                         .build();
```

I am expecting lot more similar builders for other look up tables such as StateCodeBuilder, GenderCodeBuilder and all of them have just "code" and "displayName", similar to above builder.

**I want to create a generic builder and avoid creating several builder classes doing the same job with different name.**

I attempted something in generics but I am way off..

```
public class CodeDataBuilder<T>{

    private T t;    

    public CodeDataBuilder(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public CodeDataBuilder code(String code) {
        raceCode.setCode(code);     // Cant write T.setCode here for obvious resons
        return this;
    }

    public CodeDataBuilder displayName(String displayName) {
        raceCode.setDisplayName(displayName); // Cant write T.setDisplayNamehere for obvious resons
        return this;
    }

    public T build() {
        return t;
    }

}
```

Can someone help me with that?

Thank you.

Comment: Create an interface, so that all classes implementing that interface will be guaranteed to have certain methods such as `.setCode()`. Cast `T` to that `Interface`, and you can access its methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an interface `BuildableCodeData` with the methods you need, and implement it with classes like `RaceData`.

Your code will then look like:

```
public interface BuildableCodeData {

  public void setCode(String code);

  public void setDisplayName(String name);
}

public class Builder<T extends BuildableCodeData> {
  private T codeData;

  public Builder(T codeData) {
    this.codeData = codeData;
  }

  public Builder<T> setCode(String code) {
    codeData.setCode(code);
    return this;
  }

  public Builder<T> setDisplayName(String displayName) {
    codeData.setDisplayName(displayName);
    return this;
  }

  public T build() {
    return codeData;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks abra, your solution is Clean and clear. The only thing I dont like about it is that I need to "modify" RaceData to implement my interface, what if it was a Legacy/ThirdParty class which I couldn't have changed?

Comment: Wrap it around another class that implements the interface.

Answer (score 3):

It looks more like you should use an interface, and just make your build method return that interface.  For example:

```
public interface Buildable{
    void setDisplayName(String name);
    void setCode(String code);
}

public class CodeDataBuilder {

    private Buildable mObj;    

    public CodeDataBuilder(Buildable mObj) {
        this.mObj = mObj;
    }

    public CodeDataBuilder code(String code) {
        mObj.setCode(code);     // Cant write T.setCode here for obvious resons
        return this;
    }

    public CodeDataBuilder displayName(String displayName) {
        mObj.setDisplayName(displayName); // Cant write T.setDisplayNamehere for obvious resons
        return this;
    }

    public Buildable build() {
        return mObj;
    }

}
}
```

Then just make any object you want to build implement the Buildable interface.

Comment: You'll have to cast your builder's output to the specific class every time.

Comment: True, but casts weren't really the stated issue - just not having to implement multiple builders.  It's relatively easy to extend to use generics, as shown by other answers.

Comment: Thank you Submersed, yours is the right approach, but I am accepting Abra's answer as he showed it with generics, which suited my needs and avoided explicit casting.

Answer (score 2):

If you create an interface with the needed methods:

```
interface CodeModel {
  public void setCode(String s);
  public void setDisplayName(String s);
}
```

You can then ask your generic class to accept only `T extends CodeModel`, like so:

```
class CodeDataBuilder<T extends CodeModel> {
  // T has setCode method now!
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: And how does the interface consume the generic parameter ?

Comment: Sorry about that, it was a typo. Removed the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an interface with some standard functions, you can create a generic builder for it. The base builder would be abstract, and for each concrete implementation, there would be a concrete builder.

Interface:

```
public interface CodeNameable  {
   String getCode();
   String getName();
}
```

Concrete implementation:

```
public class CodeNamedCar implements CodeNameable  {
   private String code;
   private String name;
   public CodeNamedCar(String code, String name)  {
      this.code = code;
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Abstract builder:

```
public abstract class CodeNameBuilder<C extends CodeNameable>  {
   public String code;
   public String name;
   public CodeNameBuilder()  {
   }
}
```

Concrete builder:

```
public abstract class CarBuilder extends CodeNameBuilder<CodeNamedCar>  {
   public CarBuilder()  {
   }
   public CarBuilder code(String co_de)  {
      this.code = code;
      return  this;
   }
   public CarBuilder name(String name)  {
      this.name = name;
      return  this;
   }
   public CodeNameCar build()  {
      return  (new CodeNameCar(code, name));
   }
}
```

Then you can use it as you hoped:

```
CodeNamedCar car = new CarBuilder().code("thecode").name("Mazda").build();
```

Using this design, you'll need to check each field for correctness (non-null and non-empty, for example) in the `CodeNameCar` constructor. There are other ways to design it, too.

Answer (score 0):

The builder pattern is about to crate a new instance of class and initialize it as much as required to do.

In the way you are going you tend to finish with a partial setter of some properties and create a possible fake relation because two object has the same attributes.

To support this in example everything has an name attribute but you do not create a super interface to called `Nameable` and implements its in every possible place.

If those attribute are shared across your classes you should think to create a class for them.

```
class Code {
  int number; 
  String name;
}

class Race {
  Code code;
  //other attributes; 
}
```

Then you have a one builder for code and another for race.

Note also that the good design is a balance of trade offs. If two fields are common for 5 classes is the a purpose to make the code complex and create a dedicated mechanize that will only pack the initialization and will not do anything productive.